# Proof Verification : all polynomials are continuous on R

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

I know there are quite a few posts here about this question, however I would like to see if my reasoning is valid for such a proof.

I begin by showing inductively that all monomials of degree n are continuous. More precisely, showing that the statement $p(n)$ : "$x^n$ is continuous" is true $\forall n \geq0$.

***Base Case:*** $p(0) = x^0=1$ is continuous since (by the limit point definition of continuity), $\lim _{x \to a }x^0=f(a)=a^0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$

***Inductive Hypothesis and Step:*** Assuming $p(k)$ is true for some $k>0$, show $p(k+1)$ is true.
Since,

$x^{k+1}=x^kx$
$\implies\lim _{x \to a }x^{k+1}=\lim _{x \to a }x^k \lim _{x \to a }x=a^{k}a=a^{k+1}$

$p(k+1)$ is true $\therefore$ $p(n)$ is true $\forall n\geq0$.

I then finish off my proof by stating two theorems, namely that any constant times a continuous function is still continuous and the sum of continuous functions are continuous. So, since $f(x)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is made up of the sum of monomial functions which were proved to be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

I'm quite new to proof writing so if there are things I can add to strengthen this proof or if there is some fatal flaw in general please let me know!

Comment: This is fine, though a little over complicated. For instance, the base case is just $p(x) = 1$ is continuous since $\lim_{x \to a} 1 = 1$ (no need to introduce $x^0$ since that's just $1$). The inductive step looks good assuming you know or have shown that the product of limits is the limit of the products.

Comment: Would not it be enough to prove that products and sums of continuous functions are continuous, then use induction?

Comment: This is fine; you're basically repeating the proof that the product of continuous functions is continuous (given the analogous fact about limits). If you were actually writing a text and trying to be succinct, it would be easier to reference that fact and just use induction, but your proof is also correct. Also it barely matters but its probably safer to write $1$ instead of $x^0$ just to avoid the assumption $0^0=1$.